# How to install win 7 on a iMac on Ubuntu as main OS

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, installation, multi-boot, imac

Hi im kind of new to ubuntu but im really enjoying the benefits i currently own a iMac 27" 11.1 Processor Speed: 2.66 GHz Processor Type: Core i5 (I5-750

I did a complete wipe out of the hd i try to re install os 10.6.7 w/dvd that came with the mac and i just got a stupid message saying I cant install mac os x in this computer (i have wrong dvd this mac should come with a dvd with 10.6.1 and not the 10.6.7 weird) so i got tired of (apple b***$**) and i burned a dvd with Ubuntu 13.04 on it and wiped the hd again using disk utilities from same os x DVD and actually i installed Ubuntu as main OS in my imac - i don't really care about having os x but at least there any way to install win7 doing dual booting (like bootcamp) on ubuntu ??? without using virtual box or vm player i already did a a ntfs partition using gparted but everytime i boot on dvd with win 7 i get this efi mode or the installation just get stuck on selecting language - any help will be appreciated i know is a mac, but just asking if there any way - by the way i have all bootcamp drivers and files to make windows work fine i just don't have any success at all because of EFI - I just want to have dual-booting so i am a gfx designer and i can't run photoshop in ubuntu -

Answer (score 1):

i recently just installed windows 7 onto a mac mini, using an USB drive. I used Rufus and an ISO of win7, Rufus made the pendrive bootable and everything installed fine, and then I ran bootcamp to install all the drivers to make the mac mini's hardware work in windows 7, when i partitioned the drive, i left enough space to re-install OSX Lion, so i have a great dual boot setup now.

**Edit:** Ok, so you do not want OSX, you want linux and windows dual boot, my suggesion would be to install, windows, THEN linux, since windows thinks its the only OS deserving of being on a hdd, it doesnt like to add other OS's to the boot loader most times. I have seen windows add some systems to a bootloader, but its been rare. But yes, generally thats the prferred install method, windows, then *nix.

Comment: Hi tim, thanks but i also want to keep ubuntu as my main os i just want to dual boot- so everytime i turn on my imac i have the option between ubuntu or windows 7 but i will try to install from usb drive- to see if it works ( But my concept is finding the bootcamp method but in ubuntu) cheers!

Comment: but the rufus USB tool added the efi booter for my windows installation, and it installed perfectly fine. the win7 dvd may have problems with EFI pc's (aka mac's)

Comment: Ok, thanks i will try this out - today thanks a lot-

Comment: @user173407: The Win7 DVD can boot in both BIOS and UEFI modes, but I've never tried it on a Mac with Apple's non-standard EFI implementation. Rufus is an easy way to create a UEFI mode USB installer for Win7/8, so try it out and let us know if it worked. Once you have Win7 installed in its own partition [you'll need to repair Grub](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) so you can dual-boot, but that's a later step. First get Win7 installed successfully, and be careful not to erase your Ubuntu partitions during the process.

Comment: Well i did it all and i did make a usb w win 7 using rufus but once mac start up i hit option key flash drive pop up i click it and my mac just get stuck or freeze so i dont know what else i can try.

Answer (score 0):

Install windows, and then Ubuntu. Ubuntu will work out that windows is already there and install the grub bootloader for you (kind of like a GNU bootcamp), which will let you choose which OS to start at boot.